# Powershell IE unable to click button

Tags: html, powershell, internet-explorer, automation, click

I'm working on a powershell script to update printer fields, such as location, contact person, device name, ect. and when I try to click the apply button nothing happens. I believe it is related to a hyperlink being linked because cancel would work on a few models that didn't have anything linked. I know it is the correct button because I have tried the .Focus() method and it highlights the apply button. There is an on click method listed on the apply button for onClick and it returns another method for the webpage.

Anyone ever seen anything like it or know the best way to actually click the apply button? Can I call the method that the button would be calling based on the onClick method the webpage has?

Here's some basic code that I'm using for it, pretty standard.

```
$ie = New-Object -comobject "internetexplorer.application"
$ie.visible = $true
$Webpage = ##Printer Webpage Here##
$ie.navigate($url)
while ($ie.readystate -ne 4){start-sleep 1}
$doc = $ie.document

##Puts Fields of Data needed##
$Contact = $doc.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("ContactPerson")
$Contact.value = ##contact person that should be listed##

##Presses Apply Button##
$Apply = $doc.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName("input") | ? {$_.Name -eq 'apply_button'}
$Apply.click()
```

When I change the Name of the button to 'cancel' rather than 'apply_button' it will work on some models.

Here's the buttons in HTML code I am trying to click:
[HTML inspect element for Apply and Cancel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT2AW.png)

Comment: Looks like the issue is related to compatibility mode. When I added the webpage to the list, I am able to click the apply button. Now I just need to find a way to add a lot of printers to that list automagically. I can turn on the emulator in IE to view the page, but I'm not sure how to load an IE instance in Enterprise mode through powershell.